# Git log for range across all branches (even remote)

Tags: git, git-log

I am trying the following

```
git log --before {2.days.ago} --after {14.days.ago} --all --stat
```

But it seems to only give me the log for one remote branch. I'd like to get the log for branches remote and local.

Answer (score 15):

```
git log --before {2.days.ago} --after {14.days.ago} --all --stat --branches=* --remotes=*
```

Comment: Thanks. --branches=* seems the only way to include all branches that are "out-of-line" or ahead with regard to the current HEAD.

Comment: Can you explain what `--all`, `--branches=*` and `--remotes=*` do, and whether the `--all` is redundant or not? I had a look at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log but it's a little hard to read, and didn't give in the "EXAMPLES" section how to do a listing of commits that includes all commits from local and remotes, or even a single example of using `--all`.

Comment: Not 100% sure what it does, because I just built on the original asker's question, but from what I gather, it has to do with commits that may have been "lost" due to a `git reset HEAD~1` or something like that, where the commit is only in the reflog, and not actually on a branch anymore.

Comment: This answer is misleading, `--all` implies `--branches=*` and `--remotes=*`

Answer (score 10):

> Can you explain what --all, --branches=* and --remotes=* do, and whether the --all is redundant or not?

`--all`, as mentioned in [`git rev-list`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list) or [`git rev-parse`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#_options_for_objects), --all include `--branches` or `--remotes`:

```
--all
```

> Show all refs found in refs/.

```
--branches[=pattern]
--tags[=pattern]
--remotes[=pattern]
```

> Show all branches, tags, or remote-tracking branches, respectively (i.e., refs found in `refs/heads`, `refs/tags`, or `refs/remotes`, respectively).
>
> If a pattern is given, only refs matching the given shell glob are shown.
>   If the pattern does not contain a globbing character (`?`, `*`, or `[`), it is turned into a prefix match by appending `/*`.

See as an illustration [`t/t6018-rev-list-glob.sh`#L136-L138](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8d530c4d64ffcc853889f7b385f554d53db375ed/t/t6018-rev-list-glob.sh#L136-L138):

```
test_expect_success 'rev-parse --exclude with --all' '
    compare rev-parse "--exclude=refs/remotes/* --all" "--branches --tags"
'
```

Since remote branches are requested, this should be enough:

```
git log --before {2.days.ago} --after {14.days.ago} --stat --branches --remotes
```